# High level if statement in Assembly

Tags: c, assembly

How to write a logical operator if statement in Assembly? For example in C we have the AND and OR logical functions, let's say:

**Written in C**

```
if((A >= B) && ( C < D)) {
   A = A+1;
   C = C*C;
 }else
C = C - 1;
A = C;
```

I don't know if it's correct but in assembly i translate it in this way:

**Translated in Assembly**

```
if:   cmp RA,RB
      jl else
      cmp RC,RD
      jge else
      inc RA
      mul RC,RC
      jmp endif
else: dec RC
      mov RA,RC
endif:
```

I need your help, what if I have if((A >= B) || ( C < D))?, an OR function, which changes will be applied? I saw that assembly also has logical operators(AND, OR, XOR), is it possible to us them in this case?
Could you describe an example of both cases?

Comment: Why don't you simply view the disassembly of this code under a debugger (or a compiler if possible)?

Comment: Tip: `a || b` is equivalent to `!(!a && !b)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what if I have `if((A >= B) || ( C < D))`

You can follow the same approach as your original code after applying [De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

```
if(!((A < B) && ( C >= D)))
```

> I saw that assembly also has logical operators(AND, OR, XOR), is it possible to us them in this case?

In this case, you could. However, it would no longer be equivalent to your C code, because `||` and `&&` operators use [*short-circuit evaluation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: Thanks for answering but notice that what I need is which changes are produced in the assembly, when I use the OR function instead the AND function (if((A >= B) || ( C < D)))?

Comment: @HamzaDíaz I know, I know. Please follow the link posted above to learn why the two expressions are the same.